# Edit text on text window

Tags: c++, text, window

I want to change the text that appears on a window. I seem to be able to do it okay but it messes up the area around it and hides the other text. Am I doing it the wrong way perhaps?

So I initialise the variables like this:

```
static wchar_t socketstatText1T[256];
static wchar_t socketstatText2T[256];
static HWND socketstatText1;
HWND socketstatText2;
```

I create my text windows like this:

```
socketstatText1 = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Not Connected", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
    310, 50, 200, 130, hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
socketstatText2 = CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Inactive", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
    310, 80, 200, 130, hwnd, (HMENU) 0, NULL, NULL);
```

And then I edit the text like this:

```
wcsncpy(socketstatText1T, L"Connected to socket", 18);
SetWindowTextW(socketstatText1, socketstatText1T);
```

This is the same way I change text for a text area and I've had no issues. I've also read that it works the same on text windows. So here a before and after the text change (this happens on a button press).

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfg8w.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diBm5.png)

Does anyone know what I may be missing or doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, your `CreateWindow()` calls are saying the statics should be 130 pixels tall? I don't know if it's relevant, but that would seem to just about reach as far down as the "corruption" on the after-screenshot goes.

Comment: It's always the simple things I seem to miss. Thank you for pointing this out to me!